# In a multi-container Pod, how does the restart of a single container (caused by liveness probe failure) affect the whole Pod

Tags: kubernetes

Consider a multi-container Pod where some of the containers have only the 'liveness probe' configured, some have "liveness and readiness" both probes configured, some have only "readiness probe" configured, and remaining have none of the probes configured.

Now, if liveness-probe fails for a container that had **'only' liveness-probes configured**, and kubernetes ends up restarting this container due to that, how would that restart affect the rest of the containers or the whole pod (especially during the time when this container is going through the restart process but not yet fully restarted)?

While this container is restarting, will the whole Pod be marked to be in "Not Ready" or "Error" status (and hence, will the kubernetes pause sending traffic to this Pod by removing it from service-load-balancer pool until the container successfully restarts)?